# Java vs C# method/function return-type overriding?

Tags: c#, java, inheritance

Is there a difference in the way Java and C# evaluate method/function signatures to perform overriding? In Java two methods in the child and parent, with same name and parameters, but different return types is an error- whereas in C# it compiles fine.

Am I right in thinking C# views this as overloading whereas Java attempts overriding but only allows overriding of same return types?

Comment: @L.B literally just one method in a parent class and child, same name,  no parameters, both declared protected, one returns void, the other int.

Comment: You are correct: **that is not overriding in C#**. That's *hiding*, which is a kind of *overloading*. If you *override* then the signatures must match exactly in C#, including the return type.

Comment: You must be wrong, unless you can prove it with a concrete example.

Comment: @Eric, why does C# allow hiding? Because I can still access the superclass function explicitly? I presume Java doesnt allow hiding then?

Comment: @user997112: *Disallowing* hiding makes for the obvious brittle base class failure. Allowing deliberate hiding is occasionally useful; see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/21/method-hiding-apologia.aspx. As for your question about Java: I haven't the faintest idea.

Comment: There is no hiding in instance methods in Java, only on static methods.

Comment: Actually, Java _does_ allow an overridden method to return a different type as long as that type is assignable to the superclass's method return type. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type

Answer (score 0):

you got an error in Java because the return type should be compatible with original return type.

the return type is not part of signature. however, when you override a method you should keep the return type compatible, before Java 5 the return type must be **identical**.

but now (Java 5+) you can return subclass of the original type, this called [Covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) return type.